# Make 3 lines of text change colour on hover simultaneously - help please

Tags: css, dreamweaver

Hi  I'm trying to add a colour change on hover to 3 lines of text with three different css styles within the same div.
I've added the  to the start and  to the end but the effect only works on the first line of text.
Can anyone help please?

**CSS**

```
a.specialeffects:hover {
    color: #666;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1" id="box1">
<div class="box1text" id="box1text"><a class="specialeffects"> what<br />
<span class="wedotext">we do</span><br />
<span class="wedowee">event styling &amp; design packages</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/zTqLX/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1" id="box1">
<div class="box1text" id="box1text">
    <a class="specialeffects">
        <p>what</p>
        <p><span class="wedotext">we do</span><br /></p>
        <p><span class="wedowee">event styling &amp; design packages</span></p>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.specialeffects p:hover {
    color: #F66;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To change the color all at the same time, try this:

```
.specialeffects:hover {
    color: #F66;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/zTqLX/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/zTqLX/1/)

Comment: Sorry, no - I need all three lines to change colour at the same time and then link to another page. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: I'm sorry Toni - I must be doing something wrong I still get the top word to change colour. Here's the link to the page to let you see what's going on.
http://www.creativeclout.co.uk/index.html
Thanks so much for helping

Comment: That is because you have a most specific selector: `.wedotext` that is most important than the `:hover` rule.

Comment: Nice :) You can accept my answer as correct if it helped you! I would appreciate.